# Always hidden field support in Podio API

Tags: podio

I am creating apps using Podio PHP library and want to specify always hidden setting. I have tried it a lot but I did not find any option in the library so can someone please help me to point out how I can specify this setting.

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, I am able to figure it out like how to pass the always hidden. When we are creating an app with fields then for each field we need to provide config array so in this config array we need to pass new property "hidden_create_view_edit" with true and it will create app field with always hidden setting.

Sample config array:

```
"config"=>array(
                "required"=>false,
                "label"=>"Name",
                "delta"=>1,
                "hidden_create_view_edit"=>true
            )
```